# Computing infinite sum using Parseval's theorem

Tags: sequences-and-series, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

I've been given the half-range sine series

$$f(\pi-t)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sin(2n-1)t}{(2n-1)^3}, \ \ \ \ \ \ \ 0\le t\le \pi$$

The value of series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(2n-1)^6}$ needs to be determined.

Since $f(x)$ is not directly known, how are we supposed to apply Parseval's Theorem. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The point is that $f(t)$ **is** known, since its formal second derivative constantly equals $\frac{\pi}{4}$ on $(0,\pi)$. Have a look at this very similar question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2502046/compute-zeta6-using-fourier-series

Comment: In particular $f(t)=\frac{\pi}{8}t(\pi-t)$ over $(0,\pi)$ and the problem boils down to computing the elementary integral $\int_{0}^{1}x^2(1-x)^2\,dx$.

Answer (score 0):

Using the definition of the zeta function, you have
$$\sum_{i=1}^\infty\frac{1}{(2i-1)^n}=(1-2^{-n})\,\zeta (n)$$ and the nice values for even $n$
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & \zeta (n) \\
 2 & \frac{\pi ^2}{6} \\
 4 & \frac{\pi ^4}{90} \\
 6 & \frac{\pi ^6}{945} \\
 8 & \frac{\pi ^8}{9450} \\
 10 & \frac{\pi ^{10}}{93555}
\end{array}
\right)$$