# How to find the sum of this infinite series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, summation, infinity, dirichlet-series

I am not sure how to evaluate the infinite sum:
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(2n+1)^6}$$

Apparently, I can shift it to
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(2n-1)^6}$$
which is supposed to be a well known sum that is equal to $\frac{\pi^6}{960}$. However I can't find the proof for this. Aside from this method, I found that I can also use the fourier series, but I do not know how to do this. I would greatly appreciate your help. Thank you.

Comment: Do you know [this trick](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/402451)? (look at highest score answer by user17762).

Comment: In general, for $k=1,2,...$
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty(2n+1)^{-2k}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\bigg((2n-1)^{-2k}+(2n)^{-2k}-(2n)^{-2k}\Big))$$
$$=\zeta(2k)-2^{-2k}\zeta(2k)=(1-2^{-2k})\zeta(2k)$$

Comment: Yes, or simply: for $m=2,3,\dots$$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac1{(2n+1)^m}=\zeta(m)-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{(2n)^m}=\left(1-\frac1{2^m}\right)\zeta(m).$$

Answer (score 3):

[We know that](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2502046)
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{-6}=\zeta(6)=\frac{\pi^6}{945}$$
This is absolutely convergent, so we can divide by $2^6$ to get the sum of even-$n$ terms:
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty(2n)^{-6}=\frac1{64}\zeta(6)$$
Subtracting this from the original gives the desired answer (on odd-$n$ terms):
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty(2n+1)^{-6}=\frac{63}{64}\zeta(6)=\frac{\pi^6}{960}$$